# How to use both Auto and Manual sync option with Bi-direction Azure sync data?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

My company currently set up the database on the Azure cloud. I've also set the Data Sync feature, which will allow us having the local database backup with every 5m sync automatically, it's a `From the hub` sync direction. Now we want to set up the sync group that will allow us to have `Bi-direction` sync, from Azure to the local machine and the opposite. But, we only want it to sync automatically from the Hub to the local machine, while the direction from the local machine to the Hub will be manual, which mean we can control what we sync to the Azure database (for security purpose). The reason that we need to have the local machine in our country but not in the Azure server(Singapore) is because of the internet to international usual goes down or maintenance. The Azure allows us to set up `Bi-direction` sync but only have one option for us to sync is Auto or Manual, and we cannot config it. So I want to know if there is any way that can help me to achieve that. Any advice will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From this tutorial: [Set up SQL Data Sync between Azure SQL Database and SQL Server on-premises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync#configure-sync-group).

When we set up an Azure sync group, no matter Azure SQL database or on-premises database, we all need set the `Sync Directions`:Select `Bi-directional` Sync, `To the Hub`, or `From the Hub`.

**[Add an on-premises SQL Server database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync#to-add-an-on-premises-sql-server-database)**:
[image]

For your question, how about create two SQL Data Sync groups. These two Sync groups have the same hub database. One set the on-premises database Sync Direction `From the Hub` automatic , and another set `To the Hub` manually.

Maybe you can try this.

Hope this helps.